# Is it possible to install Windows 7 Professional 64-bit on a virtual disk when starting the setup by booting the installation disc?

Tags: windows-7, setup, vhd, boot-to-vhd

I have been reading up on the native virtual hard disk support in Windows 7. The problem is installing Windows 7 on the virtual hard disk. Whenever I boot from the installation disc, follow the usual instructions to attach a vdisk and select the vdisk as the destination for the install, the setup responds with an error (I've had different errors, I'll post one the next time I reboot to try again).

There are a lot of instructions to be found on the web, for example [this blogpost on MSDN](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/setup/booting-windows-to-a-differencing-virtual-hard-disk/):

> Select the new unallocated partition
> and click Next. You may see a warning
> that reads, “Windows cannot be
> installed to this disk. (Show
> details)” but can often safely ignore
> this.

It's clear to me that ignoring this is not an option on *my* machine, but I have no idea why.

In [another article on TechNet](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/virtualization/bg-p/Virtualization) I read:

> To put a Windows 7 or Windows Server
> 2008 R2 operating system image in the
> VHD file, you have to *apply* an image
> to the partition in the VHD file.
> Running Setup from the install DVD and
> selecting a partition in a VHD file
> for installation is **not** supported.

So is it possible, unpossible (as Homer Simpson would say) or just unlikely (and thus, "**not** supported" as in the TechNet article)?

Thanks!

Comment: find/download wim2vhd then google native boot from vhd to use the resultant file!

Comment: I have looked at it, but you need the WAIK and if you have that you already have all you need to apply an image to a vhd. Anyway, thanks for the tip, though it doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend burning your Windows 7 install disk to a ISO Image .   Then, mount the .iso image as a CDRom for your VMWare system.   I'm not saying that is the answer but I bet you learn a lot from it.